# SqlCeDataReader is always null

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

Hey Guys I'm working on Windows Mobile 5.0 (.Net 2.0) 
and I'm stuck at a small problem where my reader is always being null. My connection is fine and I believe everything else is fine the only problem is with the reader.
In my exception catch it says

```
((System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException)(e)) :  {"The operation completed successfully."}
InnerException: Could not evaluate expression
```

My database file is not corrupt I opened it outside the application and everything looks fine.
My code is as follows:

```
  public static List<Image> GetAll(BOI caller)
    {
        List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        SqlCeConnection c = Connection.GetConnection(caller.ConnectionString);

        if (c != null)
        {
            SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Images", c);

            SqlCeDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();  <<<<< reader is null <<<<<<<
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                while (reader != null && reader.Read())
                {
                    Image temp = new Image((int)reader["imageKey"],
                              (String)reader["filename"],
                              (byte[])reader["image"],
                              (reader["labelKey"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["labelKey"]),
                              (int)reader["priority"]);
                    temp.SetDBName(caller.ConnectionString);

                    images.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        return images;
    }
```

**EDIT**
I open my connection in Connection.GetConnection(..);

**EDIT:2**
The e.StackTrace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.FillMetaData(SqlCeCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.InitializeDataReader(SqlCeDataReader reader, Int32 resultType)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Oralys.BOI.DataAccess.ImageMapper.GetAll(BOI caller)
   at Oralys.BOI.BOI.get_Images()
   at Oralys.BOI.BOI_Controller.FetchAllImages()
   at IdeoVoiceMobile.RunProfile.InitBOI()
   at IdeoVoiceMobile.RunProfile..ctor()
   at IdeoVoiceMobile.Program.startProfile()
   at IdeoVoiceMobile.Program.Main()
```

Get Connection function:

```
    public static SqlCeConnection GetConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            if (connections.Count == 0)
            {
                OpenConnection(connectionString);
            }
            conn = connections[connectionString];
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

**EDIT:3**
Exception code when using

> SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Images Where
>   imageKey=6", c);

```
ExceptionCode: 0xc0000005
ExceptionAddress: 0x0115438c
Reading: 0x00000000
Faulting module: sqlceqp35.dll
Offset: 0x0001438c

   at NativeMethods.GetKeyInfo(IntPtr pIUnknown, IntPtr pTx, String pwszBaseTable, IntPtr prgDbKeyInfo, Int32 cDbKeyInfo, IntPtr pError)
   at SqlCeDataReader.FillMetaData(SqlCeCommand command)
   at SqlCeCommand.InitializeDataReader(SqlCeDataReader reader, Int32 resultType)
   at SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ImageMapper.GetAll(BOI caller)
   at BOI.get_Images()
   at BOI_Controller.FetchAllImages()
   at RunProfile.InitBOI()
   at RunProfile..ctor()
   at Program.startProfile()
   at Program.Main()
```

Comment: Showing the next few lines of code would be helpful

Comment: I can't see you explicitly opening the connection? Is that in `GetConnection`?

Comment: Yea was going to edit my question to write that.

Comment: Have you cut and pasted the code incorrectly? I'm guessing that you don't read from the reader object in the catch (Exception e) block?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush `reader = command.ExecuteReader();` is null before the catch exception block.

Comment: Change this while (reader != null && reader.Read())
 you only need to while(reader.Read())

Comment: @DJKRAZE As I said before the reader is null before it hits the catch. I get the following exception `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Is it a problem with the 'image' field type or length of data? Try running the query with specifying imageKey, FileName, LabelKey and Priority instead of '*', see if omitting image stops the error.

Comment: can you show what this code looks like SqlCeConnection c = Connection.GetConnection(caller.ConnectionString);
 I am wondering if you are setting the Command.CommandType for example.. thanks

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I did that, I got this error: A native exception has occured. Select Quit and then restart this program. ExceptionCode:0xc0000005 Faulting module: sqlceqp35.dll

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I updated the question with exception code.

Comment: I presume the connection has been successfully opened, you've checked that it's not null? Does it still error if you simplify the query to SELECT imageKey FROM Images?

Comment: The connection is not null, when I try to simplify the query I get the native exception error thing. I posted the whole error in the question.

Comment: Can you query any other tables in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up to be because I was using `System.Data.SqlServerCe 3.5.1.0` when I switched to `3.5.0.0` it worked without any error. 
And I put the while loop outside the catch statement.

But I'm still annoyed from MS because they didnt show any error regarding that!

Comment: This solution has **everything** to do with moving the loop outside of the catch and little or nothing to do with changing the version of the sql server compact provider.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No your wrong. I moved the loop outside the catch and it still gave me an error. Then I changed the version of sql dll and it worked fine.

Comment: @raym0nd: Then you had mismatched binaries on the PC and the target device.  There are many of use using 3.5.1 without any problem.  You have to compile against the proper version and deploy that same version to the target, else you get weird behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never hit the following line of code unless cm.executereader throws an exception:

```
while (reader != null && reader.Read())
```

Try moving the below code outside of the catch statement

```
            while (reader != null && reader.Read())
            {
                Image temp = new Image((int)reader["imageKey"],
                          (String)reader["filename"],
                          (byte[])reader["image"],
                          (reader["labelKey"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["labelKey"]),
                          (int)reader["priority"]);
                temp.SetDBName(caller.ConnectionString);

                images.Add(temp);
            }
```

Comment: Do I have to ? I dont think I need to specify the command type.

Comment: That's a red herring anyway.  Default is "Text" which is ok in this instance.  Do you check the connection state in Connection.GetConnection?

Comment: The connection is fine and its open.

Comment: Do you have any further information.  Could you specify the stack trace?

Comment: No idea.  I'd pull the database from the device, connect to it using SSMS and execute the same query.

Comment: I already did that :| the query works fine. I've been trying to debug this forever with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Raym0nd, I'm guessing you are new at this.

Take a look at this version of what you provided.

```
public static List<Image> GetAll(BOI caller) {
  List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
  using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Images", Connection.GetConnection(caller.ConnectionString))) {
    try {
      cmd.Connection.Open();
      using (SqlCeReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
          object imageKey = reader["imageKey"];
          object filename = reader["filename"];
          object image = reader["image"];
          object labelKey = reader["labelKey"];
          object priority = reader["priority"];
          Image img = new Image((interface)imageKey, (string)filename, (byte[])image, (int?)labelKey, (int)priority);
          img.SetDBName(caller.ConnectionString);
          images.Add(img);
        }
      }
    } catch (SqlCeException err) {
      Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
      throw err;
    } finally {
      cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
  }
  return images;
}
```

You'll want to add some functionality to test your objects in the case of your nullable integer, but for the most part is is clean and simple.

Put a break point on the `Console.WriteLine()`, and mouse over the `Message` if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks that helped... but the problem was because I was using System.Data.SqlServerCe version 3.5.1.0 I used the 3.5.0.0 and it worked like a charm.